# How can I create a boxplot of within-group euclidian distances for grouped data?

Tags: r, plot, distance, boxplot, euclidean-distance

Example data:

```
set.seed(1234)
a <- matrix(rnorm(250),nrow=25,ncol=10)
fac <- as.factor(c(rep("A",8),rep("B",10),rep("C",7)))
a.dist <- dist(a, "euclidian")
boxplot(a.dist ~ fac)
```

When I try to run `boxplot(a.dist ~ fac)`, I get the following error:

```
Error in model.frame.default(formula = a.dist ~ fac) : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'fac')
```

I tried to fix this by

```
a.dist <- as.matrix(a.dist)
a.dist[upper.tri(a.dist)] <- NA
```

but then `boxplot` returns me a funny plot.

I could plot the within-group euclidean distances of a specific group with

```
subset <- as.factor(fac) %in% ("A")
a.dist.A <- a.dist[subset]
boxplot(a.dist.A)
```

Essentially I need to do this for each factor level then combine those boxplots to a single one. Is there an easy way for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
set.seed(1234)
a <- matrix(rnorm(250),nrow=25,ncol=10)
fac <- as.factor(c(rep("A",8),rep("B",10),rep("C",7)))

a_grp <- split.data.frame(a, fac)    ## split matrix by group
d_grp <- lapply(a_grp, dist)         ## apply `dist` by group
n_grp <- lengths(d_grp)              ## number of pairs by group
d <- unlist(d_grp)                   ## combine
g <- rep(factor(levels(fac), levels = levels(fac)), n_grp)  ## combine
boxplot(d ~ g)                       ## joint plot
```

[image]

Applying `dist` by group is necessary as you don't want between-group distance.